# Will symbolic links still work after a Windows reinstall?

Tags: windows-10, symbolic-link, reinstall

I'd like to reinstall Windows and create a clean system image, but, before I do that, I would like to create symbolic links (for file organization purposes).

The links are not on the C:\ (OS) drive; so, when I reinstall Windows, will the links still work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean the following:

> Have a harddrive which has a C and D partition, and the symlinks are on the D partition prior to the reinstallation where the D partition is not affected.

If the above is the case, then yes, after a reinstallation, the symlinks will remain in effect, even if they point to folders on the C drive, and it doesn't matter if those folders are altered by the reinstallation.

If for some reason after the reinstallation the Symlink points to a location that no longer exists, the symlink itself remains in effect, it is just treated like what normally happens if you create a symlink to a folder, then remove its destination, or create a symlink to a non-existing folder. Upon attempting to access the folder, it will give a "this file/folder does not exist" error.

If the symlinks are on the C drive, then, depending on where they are located they will or will not be replaced by the windows reinstallation. Basically all folders that are created/modified by the windows installation will overwrite the symlink. So C:\Users, C:\Program Files (and x86 version) C:\ProgramData and C:\Windows (including sub folders) are all affected in this way.

But C:\MySymLink will not be overwritten unless you format the C:\ drive during install, or choose remove files during Windows Reset.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! If the sym links and their destinations are on a drive that is not being affected by a re install on the C: drive, they will still work.

Comment: This is incorrect. Symlinks will not be affected after a windows install if they are not on the C drive, though many places on the C drive will still work, but you can't just copy a symlink and expect it to work. It depends on the kind of link and what you use to copy too.

Comment: I took the question to mean all of the linked files and their sym links are on an external drive. If so, I don't see how re imaging the C: drive would affect this.

Comment: I referred to the part you now edited out.

Comment: Yes, after re reading my comment I saw how it wasn't clear so I updated it.